# Separate values ​with commas or "&" symbol under conditions

Tags: php, html, wordpress, separator, multiple-conditions

I'm using an ACF custom field in WordPress to display co-authors to my posts.

```
function display_authors() { ?>

<div class="post-authors">
    
    <div class="post-default_author">By
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php the_author(); ?>
        </a>
    </div><?php
    
    $users = get_field("co_authors");
    if( $users ): ?>

    <div class="post-co_authors">
        <?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
        <span class="post-co_author">and <a href="/blog/author/<?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></a></span>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div><?php

}
```

My code is fine when there is only one co-author, it displays: `By DEFAULT_AUTHOR and CO_AUTHOR`.

But when there are several, it displays "and" before each co-author. The right presentation should be: `By DEFAULT_AUTHOR, CO_AUTHOR_1 and CO_AUTHOR_2`.

I try to display a comma after the default author and each co-author otherwise display the symbol "&" before the last/only co-author.

I need help to get this result. Also, I don't know if my HTML tags allow it because they add spaces.

**EDIT:**

I recomposed my code slightly and cheated with CSS.

PHP:

```
<div class="post-authors">By 
    <?php
    $users = get_field("co_authors");
    if( $users ): ?>
    <span class="post-co_authors"><?php
    foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
        <span class="post-co_author"><a href="/blog/author/<?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></a></span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
</div><?php
}
```

CSS:

```
.post-co_author::after {
    content: ", ";
}
.post-co_author:only-child::after,
.post-co_author:last-child::after {
    content: " & ";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not check whether the loop body is evaluated for the first time or not, and act accordingly? Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - this question is in no way related to HTML, or Wordpress itself

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter in order to check if you're not on the first loop, to do so, you can make a for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
 if($i > 0){
  echo ' and ';
 }
 echo $users[$i];
}
```

If you prefer to use a foreach loop, just add a $i = 0; before the foreach and increment it at the end of your foreach.

Comment: I failed to put it into practice properly after several tries... my php skills are lacking... I cheated with the CSS, see the edit of the main post. Thank you anyway for your contribution.